# How should one interpret Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) in a clustering problem?

Tags: performance, cluster-analysis

I have been working on a clustering algorithm with 6900 samples for two clusters. I used ARI for analysing the performance of my clustering algorithm and got 0.52.

My problem is with the interpretation of this number. Can I derive a sensible meaning out of it?  Or 'the more positive the better' explanation is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You calculate the ARI with your clustering result and some other label assignment. The ARI tells you how close your result is to this other label assignment, adjusted for the chance of random correct guesses. A higher positive ARI means a higher concordance between the two labellings.